# BxAndroidBle cannot read device, status=22

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I am having troubles with reading a Ble device and using the RxAndroidBle library.

I keep getting this error:

```
BleGattException{status=22, bleGattOperation=BleGattOperation{description='CONNECTION_STATE'}}
```

Can anyone look at my code and see what I might be doing wrong:

```
subscription = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(context, true)
            .subscribe(rxBleConnection -> {
                rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UUID_LOG_COUNT)).doOnNext(Action1 -> Logger.d(Helper_Utils.reverseHex(HexString.bytesToHex(Action1))));
            }, throwable -> {
                Logger.d("Error", throwable.getMessage());
            });
```

If you need more info, I will try to provide it.

EDIT

I have used 2 different phones:
OnePlus Two Android 6.0.1
Moto G Play Android 6.0.1

I have tried multiple times switching wifi and bluetooth on and off.
I have never been able to get a reading with this example.

Comment: Could you provide info about what phone / OS you use? You can also check if it will happen again after you will switch off and on again both WiFi and BT adapter.

Comment: @s_noopy I have edited my answer. I have never gotten a reading, doesn't matter how many times I try.

Comment: To get an Observable working you need to subscribe to it.

Comment: @s_noopy I am no expert in RxJava, but haven't I subscribed to it? Can you give an example please.

Comment: You have only subscribed to `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()`. After that you have created a read by `RxBleConnection.readCharacteristic()` but you have not subscribed to it. Could you clarify if `status == 22` is still the issue?

Comment: Any news? Could you set `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)` and paste the logs from the app into the original post?

Comment: @s_noopy thank you for pointing me in the right direction, if you post an answer here I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status = 22` is a problem related to Android OS disconnecting your peripheral. There is not much you can do from the code to prevent it.

As for not reading the characteristic value — it is because you are not subscribing to it. The best approach in `RxJava` programming (or reactive programming in general) is to prepare a flow with only a single subscribe because then you minimise the amount of state.

You could do like this:

```
Subscription s = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(true) // establish the connection
  .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UUID_LOG_COUNT))) // when the connection is established start reading the characteristic
  .take(1) // after the first value unsubscribe from the upstream to close the connection
  .subscribe( // subscribe to read values
    characteristicValue -> Logger.d(Helper_Utils.reverseHex(HexString.bytesToHex(characteristicValue))), // do your thing with the read value here
    throwable -> Logger.d("Error", throwable.getMessage()) // log / show possible error here
  );
```

Remember that the result of `.subscribe()` is a `Subscription` which you can cancel by calling `Subscription.unsubscribe()` which will disconnect the peripheral.

My code is referencing the new API that was introduced by `RxAndroidBle 1.2.0` which was released yesterday.

Comment: How do you know what status 22 is? Where are the error codes?

Comment: It is all described in the current implementation of [`BleGattException`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/exceptions/BleGattException.java) which points you to [this Android source code file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h). You want to search for `0x16` which is 22 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you s_noopy for finding my problem.

This was the solution for my problem:

```
subscription = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(context, true)
        .subscribe(rxBleConnection -> {
           rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UUID_LOG_COUNT))
.subscribe(characteristicValue -> {
                            Logger.d(Helper_Utils.reverseHex(HexString.bytesToHex(characteristicValue)));
                        });
        }, throwable -> {
            Logger.d("Error", throwable.getMessage());
        });
```

I changed the .doOnNext with .subscribe